# in CGI, how it is possible to use both python code and html code

Tags: python, html, forms, cgi

How can I use both HTML and Python code in same file  in CGI as we can do the same thing wiht PHP and HTML.
I have following HTML code in Python file.

```
#!C:/python36/python.exe
import cgi
print("Content-type:text/html")
print("""
<html>
<head><title>html form</title></head>
<body style='background-color:red;'>
<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
<input type="text" placeholder="password" name="password">
<input type="submit"   value="submit" name="send">
</html>""")
```

now I want use python code in this file to get form data and my python code is as follow:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

username = form.getvalue("username")
password = form.getvalue("password")
print(username,password)
```

Now, if submit is clicked, I want Python code to be executed and also I do not want to reference my Python code in form action.

Comment: Your question is really unclear, can you try rephrasing what the problem you're trying to solve is? And, at any rate, you almost certainly don't want to be using `cgi`. You probably want to look into a framework, such as `Flask` that uses jinja templating.

Comment: The `cgi` module is ok for very simple stuff, but it is rather limited (and CGI is considered very old-fashioned these days), and it gets positively painful if you're trying to do anything more complex. Why don't you want to put the name of your Python CGI script in your form's `action` attribute?